# Detect mobile browser close event for a mobile

Tags: reactjs, browser, progressive-web-apps, dom-events

I want to perform some operation when my application gets killed. Which method can be used for this? I am working on React Js.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the whole browser from being killed isn't possible, as that behaviour could easily be exploited by malicious scripts. You can, however, detect when the tab is closed.

Try the [window: beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: yes I have done this as well.. this works when I try to close the tab of the browser. but What I am trying is when user kills the browser that time. I wan to show one pop up message

Comment: That is simply not possible. If it were possible, it would be exploited by malicious scripts.